# Regex to match certain lines, except when they have certain words (limited regex vocab available)

Tags: regex, string, logfile-analysis

I'm using a log tailing app (BareTailPro) that highlights rows which match regular expressions. I currently have the filter set to just `error` (ignore case on) which returns, for example:

```
25/07/2011 00:09:43.384 [Error] Timeout elapsed
25/07/2011 01:44:04.541 [Error] Receiver TopicName message count changed
25/07/2011 06:07:23.648 [Error] Error processing files
25/07/2011 09:40:04.591 [Error] Receiver TopicName message count changed
25/07/2011 16:42:12.163 [Error] Error Getting Matches & Rejects
```

I don't want to see the rows with `Receiver TopicName.*`.

Is it possible to set up a regex to do this? The app seems to have an extremely limited expression vocabulary: [reference](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretailpro/regex.php?app=BareTailPro&ver=2.50aR&date=2006-11-02)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given Dogbert's answer which says there's no negative lookahead I suggest this:

If you know what all the possible things that come after error are, for example `Timeout`, `Error`, `Error Getting Matches`, etc... You could add all of that to your regexp. So instead of matching error, you could match `error (Timeout|Error|Error Getting  Matches)` and so on.

It is not a perfect solution (and you run the risk of missing some), but it could work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible as there's no look ahead statement support mentioned on that page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [a negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) if BareTailPro supports it.